# PDF Links in Website are not showing content on Webview. I Am currently using Googledocs

Tags: java, android

PDF Links in Website are not showing content on Webview. I Am currently using Googledocs.

This is my java code

```
demoscad.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
demoscad.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
demoscad.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
demoscad.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
demoscad.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
demoscad.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
demoscad.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
demoscad.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
demoscad.getSettings().getAllowContentAccess();
demoscad.getSettings().getAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs();
demoscad.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
        if (progress >= 100) {
        }
    }
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error){
        //Your code to do
        Toast.makeText(DemosCAD.this, "This is my Toast message!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
String demos = "https:xxxxx + userId;
        String googledocs = "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=";
        demoscad.loadUrl(demos + googledocs);
        demoscad.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        demoscad.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
```

Comment: Your `loadUrl` must be `demoscad.loadUrl(googledocs + demos);` 
`googledocs` first before your url.

Answer (score 0):

First add  googledocs url then your add custom url so it should be like this

```
demoscad.loadUrl(googledocs+demos);
```

like this

```
    String demos = "https://xxx" + userId;
    String googledocs = "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=";
    demoscad.loadUrl(googledocs+demos);
    demoscad.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    demoscad.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback but the webpage fails to load using your method.

Comment: for what? The webpage displays the pdf when launched in browser